# Updating the column that the table was joined on

Tags: sql, join, sql-update

I need to update a column that two tables were joined on and I'm having a difficult time wrapping my head around it. This is for SQL Server. Loose example below...

**User**

```
ID | Name | GroupID |
---------------------
1  | Bob  |   100   |
2  | Alex |   300   |
3  | Sara |   300   |
```

**Group**

```
ID   |   Name  | 
----------------
100  | Produce |
200  | Cashier |
300  | Stocker |
```

GroupID is a foreign key to the Group table and they are being joined on that. I HAVE to update the GroupID column in User based on the Name column in Group. For example, I want Alex and Sara to change from 'Stocker' to 'Cashier'. My solution is below, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
UPDATE User
SET User.GroupID = G.ID
FROM User U
    JOIN Group G ON U.GroupID = G.ID
WHERE User = 'Sara' OR User = 'Alex'
```

Expected Result

**User**

```
ID | Name | GroupID |
---------------------
1  | Bob  |   100   |
2  | Alex |   200   |
3  | Sara |   200   |
```

Comment: which db  you are using ???

Comment: *WHERE User = 'Sara' AND User = 'Alex'* - how do you envisage this to return any rows? User can't be two different values at the same time.

Comment: You have not relation between name in group and name in  user ..  try explain better ..  add also the expected  result

Comment: I really don't have an idea what you are trying to do here... " I want Alex and Sara to change from 'Stocker' to 'Cashier'" -> based on your tables that makes no sense.

Comment: @ScaisEdge SQL Server

Comment: @Stu Sorry, that should have been OR not AND

Comment: @ScaisEdge GroupID is a foreign key to the Group table. That's the relationship between the two tables. I added the expected result.

Comment: @XraySensei I updated the code. I had a mistype in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need  and updated  with join  ..
but you could use a subquery for get the expected  id from group

```
update user 
set User.GroupID = (select id 
from group where name = 'Cashier )
where User = 'Sara' OR User = 'Alex'
```